# How pass parameters from two url without show them in the url

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I need to pass parameters from URLA o urlB whithout and the urlB must be show ( so I can't use `skiplocation=true`).

in my ts I do ( in URLA) :

```
this.router.navigate([URLB], {
                queryParams:
                {
                    name: "erika"

                }
            });
```

and when I take the parameter I do:

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = params['name'];

    });
```

The problem is that it shows me url in this way `URLB?name=erika` and I don't want to do this, but i want the it show me URLB and pass me hidden parameter. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.  it's not clear what you want. I suggest you not using query string or path variable because query string and path variable paramter are visible. The only way that i know to have invisible parameter is to use the payload like in the HTTP POST verb.

Comment: its not possible. what you can do is keep to url to URL A and still navigate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass invisible or hidden parameters using routerLink Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905336/pass-invisible-or-hidden-parameters-using-routerlink-angular)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the state in NavigationExtras:

Set data:

```
this.router.navigate(['yoururl'], { state: yourObject });
```

Get data:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
```

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

If you want to use a service, read this: [Sharing Data between Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726860/sharing-data-between-components-angular-7)